# Creating hand cursor on a UIButton in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I am a beginner in xcode, I want to know how can I implement creating a hand cursor when I hover over a UIButton in xcode?

Comment: please explain? Do you want to modify xCode or your application? Beacuse an UIButton belongs to iOS, there is no hover effect, as you can't hover on a touch device!

Comment: @yan.kun- i was trying to modify my application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot hover on an iOS device since there is no cursor. It sounds like you're trying to do something nonstandard on a touch device, I suggest reading the iOS Human Interface Guideline document to get familiar with the common interactions.